# Group, Sum byType then get diff using Java streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I would like to use stream to group, get the sum by type, then find the result of the different by type.

So this is my data set.

```
Sample(SampleId=1, SampleTypeId=1, SampleQuantity=5, SampleType=ADD), 
Sample(SampleId=2, SampleTypeId=1, SampleQuantity=15, SampleType=ADD), 
Sample(SampleId=3, SampleTypeId=1, SampleQuantity=25, SampleType=ADD), 
Sample(SampleId=4, SampleTypeId=1, SampleQuantity=5, SampleType=SUBTRACT), 
Sample(SampleId=5, SampleTypeId=1, SampleQuantity=25, SampleType=SUBTRACT) 
Sample(SampleId=6, SampleTypeId=2, SampleQuantity=10, SampleType=ADD), 
Sample(SampleId=7, SampleTypeId=2, SampleQuantity=20, SampleType=ADD), 
Sample(SampleId=8, SampleTypeId=2, SampleQuantity=30, SampleType=ADD), 
Sample(SampleId=9, SampleTypeId=2, SampleQuantity=15, SampleType=SUBTRACT), 
Sample(SampleId=10, SampleTypeId=2, SampleQuantity=35, SampleType=SUBTRACT)
```

My current method of doing is as such:

```
Map<Long, Integer> result = sampleList.stream()
.collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(
        Sample::getSampleTypeId, 
        Collectors.summingInt(Sample::getSampleQuantity)
        )
    );
```

and my result is as such (SampleTypeId, result):

```
{1=75, 2=110}
```

I'm not sure how to continue from here. Basically, there is a SampleType of either ADD or SUBTRACT. So I need to SUM all the TypeId=1 and Type=ADD AND SUM all the typeId=1 and Type=SUBSTRACT then find the difference.

Example

```
1 >> (5+15+25) - (5+25) = 15
2 >> (10+20+30) - (15+35) = 10
```

So the expected output should be `{1=15, 2=10}`.

Comment: Stream solution would actually read along the lines of how you describe what you need. Every `then` or `and` would be replaced with a collector by chaining `collectingAndThen` calls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Collectors are a very powerful feature in Java 8, because each of them can be composed of different blocks, and even then, there is a simple way to compose collectors themselves.

This solution is solved by such `Collector` composition, below I'll guide you through the steps towards the solution.

First of all, we start from the first requirement: the result has to be a dictionary keyed with `TypeId`:

```
Map<TypeId, List<Sample>> r = stream.collect(
  Collectors.groupingBy(Sample::getTypeId)
);
```

Second, among each `TypeId` list we need to make sub-groups by `Type`. For that, we use an extended version of Grouping By collector, which allows us to specify what we should do once we classified elements and assigned them to groups. In out case, we need to classify them again:

```
Map<TypeId, Map<Type, List<Sample>>> r = stream.collect(
  groupingBy(Sample::getTypeId,
    groupingBy(Sample::getType))
);
```

Now, once both classifiers are done, we need to sum quantities among all the elements within group. The technique is the same: we tell what to do with group elements after classifier is run. In this case, sum all the amounts:

```
Map<TypeId, Map<Type, Integer>> r = stream.collect(
  groupingBy(Sample::getTypeId,
    groupingBy(Sample::getType, Collectors.summingInt(Sample::getQuantity))
  )
);
```

Next, the most interesting part: we need to do an operation on the `Map<Type, Integer>`. More specifically, we need to do `map[Add] - map[Sub]`. The most important notion of this step is we want to do it once all the other collecting operations are complete, before returning result. This is an operation which can only happen at the stage of the stream collection called `Collector.finisher`. We can compose finishers of arbitrary collectors by calling `collectingAndThen` method of `Collectors` class:

```
Map<TypeId, Integer> r = stream.collect(
  groupingBy(Sample::getTypeId,
    Collectors.collectingAndThen(
      groupingBy(Sample::getType, summingInt(Sample::getQuantity)),
      map -> map.getOrDefault(SampleType.ADD, 0) - map.getOrDefault(SampleType.SUBTRACT, 0)
    )
  )
);
```

That's all. Note that it's important to call `getOrDefault` instead of `get`, because there might not've been any elements with some specific `SampleType`, and map would otherwise return `null`, causing the whole thing to collapse with `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain the 2nd portion on why was it after the 2nd groupingBy, it turns from a Map<TypeId, List<Sample>> to Map<TypeId, Map<Type, Sample>>? And not a Map<TypeId, Map<Type, List<Sample>>>?

Also, if there is another SampleType of say SampleType.XXX, I can add into the map -> (ADD) - (SUBSTRACT) * (XXX) depending on my formula right?

And thanks for the clear explanation, it helps alot!

Comment: @user1778855, it actually does turn into `Map<TypeId, Map<Type, List<Sample>>>`, that was my mistake.

Comment: @user1778855, yes, you can add more operation types to the formula, and it would behave the same. You can write almost anything in finisher, as long as it in this case accepts a `Map<Type, Integer>` and returns `Integer`. Although you wouldn't be able to use v2 of @user7's answer in case that other type is anything other than `ADD` and `SUB`. `MUL` and `DIV` operations would only be possible with collector finisher. And if your formula becomes complex, I would suggest you extract it into a method so it doesn't shadow the rest of the code.

Comment: thanks for your explanation. Appreciate it. I have since updated my questions with some more query. Hope you could assist me in understanding how I can achieve it as well. Thank you.

Comment: @user1778855, if you have more questions on top of this one, please ask another separate question. By constantly adding to original one you are moving a goal post. For example, my answer no longer qualifies to be the correct one, even though it is accepted. So, roll back your edits and ask a new question. If you want me to quickly find it, comment here.

Comment: alright, have made the edits, and posted in a new thread. You can find it here > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49541062/java-8-group-collectors-map-int-to-string-map-map-to-object <

Answer (score 2):

```
sampleList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Sample::getSampleTypeId,
                Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.groupingBy(Sample::getSampleType,
                        Collectors.summingInt(Sample::getSampleQuantity)),
                        map -> (map.getOrDefault(SampleType.ADD, 0) 
                                - map.getOrDefault(SampleType.SUBTRACT, 0)))));
```

The outer `groupingBy` groups by `sampleTypeId`.
At the next level,  it involves the construction of map with key `SampleType` and value the sum of `SampleQuantity` for a key. The *finisher* of the `collectingAndThen` subtracts the value of ADD and SUBTRACT to give the final result.

Version 2 (even simpler):

```
sampleList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Sample::getSampleTypeId,
                Collectors.summingInt(sample -> sample.getSampleType() == SampleType.SUBTRACT
                        ? -sample.getSampleQuantity() :
                        sample.getSampleQuantity()
                )));
```

It does not construct the second map that was constructed earlier. It simply checks whether the SampleType is ADD or SUBTRACT and returns the sampleQuantity appropriately.

Comment: Thanks! v2 makes it easier to visualise the code. v1 is essentially the same as @M. Prokhorov. Both solution works exactly the way I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

The following:

```
1 >> ( 5 + 15 + 25) - ( 5 + 25) = 15
2 >> (10 + 20 + 30) - (15 + 35) = 10
```

is exactly the same as this:

```
1 >>  5 + 15 + 25 -  5 - 25 = 15
2 >> 10 + 20 + 30 - 15 - 35 = 10
```

So you could take advantage of this and avoid nested-grouping by `SampleType`. Instead, just either sum or subtract on the downstream collector:

```
Map<Long, Integer> result = sampleList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Sample::getSampleTypeId, 
        Collectors.summingInt(sample -> sample.getSampleQuantity() * 
                (SampleType.ADD.equals(sample.getSampleType()) ? 1 : -1))));
```

---

Even better, if you could create a method in the `Sample` class:

```
public int getCalculatedQuantity() {
    return sampleQuantity * (SampleType.ADD.equals(sampleType) ? 1 : -1);
}
```

Then use it as follows:

```
Map<Long, Integer> result = sampleList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Sample::getSampleTypeId, 
        Collectors.summingInt(Sample::getCalculatedQuantity)));
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be a simpler way with just map:

```
Map<Long, Integer> result = sampleList.stream()
.map(sample->{if(sample.getSampleType==SUBTRACT)
     return new Sample((sample.SampleId, 
                        sample.SampleTypeId, 
                        sample.SampleQuantity*(-1), 
                        sample.SampleType))

     return sample;
 })
.collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(
        Sample::getSampleTypeId, 
        Collectors.summingInt(Sample::getSampleQuantity)
        )
    );
```