# Group, Collectors, Map (Int to String), Map (Map to Object)

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

This is a continuation of my previous question at [Group, Sum byType then get diff using Java streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49538341/java-8-group-sum-bytype-then-get-diff).

As suggested, I should post as a separate thread instead of updating the original one.

So with my previous set of question, I have achieved that, and now, with the continuation.

Background:

I have the following dataset

```
Sample(SampleId=1, SampleTypeId=1, SampleQuantity=5, SampleType=ADD), 
Sample(SampleId=2, SampleTypeId=1, SampleQuantity=15, SampleType=ADD), 
Sample(SampleId=3, SampleTypeId=1, SampleQuantity=25, SampleType=ADD), 
Sample(SampleId=4, SampleTypeId=1, SampleQuantity=5, SampleType=SUBTRACT), 
Sample(SampleId=5, SampleTypeId=1, SampleQuantity=25, SampleType=SUBTRACT) 
Sample(SampleId=6, SampleTypeId=2, SampleQuantity=10, SampleType=ADD), 
Sample(SampleId=7, SampleTypeId=2, SampleQuantity=20, SampleType=ADD), 
Sample(SampleId=8, SampleTypeId=2, SampleQuantity=30, SampleType=ADD), 
Sample(SampleId=9, SampleTypeId=2, SampleQuantity=15, SampleType=SUBTRACT), 
Sample(SampleId=10, SampleTypeId=2, SampleQuantity=35, SampleType=SUBTRACT)
```

I am currently using this:

```
sampleList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Sample::getTypeId,
        Collectors.summingInt(
            sample -> SampleType.ADD.equalsIgnoreCase(sample.getSampleType())
                ? sample.getSampleQuantity() :
                -sample.getSampleQuantity()
            )));
```

And also this

```
sampleList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Sample::getSampleTypeId,
                Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(Sample::getSampleType,
                        Collectors.summingInt(Sample::getSampleQuantity)),
                            map -> map.getOrDefault(SampleType.ADD, 0)
                                    - map.getOrDefault(SampleType.SUBTRACT, 0))));
```

as the accepted answer to get the desired output to group in a `Map<Long, Integer>`:

```
{1=15, 2=10}
```

With that, I was wondering, if this could be expanded into something more.

First, how could I have it return as a `Map<String, Integer>` instead of the original `Map<Long, Integer>`. Basically, for the SampleTypeId; 1 refers to HELLO, 2 refers to WORLD.

So I would need like a `.map` (or maybe other function) to transform the data from 1 to HELLO and 2 to WORLD by calling a function say `convertType(sampleTypeId)`?. So the expected output would then be `{"HELLO"=15, "WORLD"=10}`. Is that right? How should I edit the current suggested solution to this?

Lastly, I would like to know if it is also possible to return it to a Object instead of a `Map`. So let's say I have a Object; `SummaryResult with (String) name and (int) result`. So it returns a `List<SummaryResult>` instead of the original `Map<Long, Integer>`. How can I use the `.map` (or other) feature to do this? Or is there other way to doing so? The expected output would be something along this line.

```
SummaryResult(name="hello", result=15), 
SummaryResult(name="world", result=10),
```

Would really appreciate it with the explanation in steps as given previously by @M. Prokhorov.

Update:

After updating to

```
sampleList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(sample -> convertType(sample.getSampleTypeId()),
                Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(Sample::getSampleType,
                        Collectors.summingInt(Sample::getSampleQuantity)),
                            map -> map.getOrDefault(SampleType.ADD, 0)
                                    - map.getOrDefault(SampleType.SUBTRACT, 0))));

private String convertType(int id) {
    return (id == 1) ? "HELLO" : "WORLD";
}
```

Comment: Each question should be complete. While link can be nice as *additional* resource it can't be *only* source to info necessary to understand your question.

Comment: @Pshemo noted, I have since updated the question with some background info. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For first part, considering you have somewhere the method

```
String convertType(int typeId)
```

You simply need to change first classifier from this

```
groupingBy(SampleType::getTypeId)
```

to this

```
groupingBy(sample -> convertType(sample.getTypeId()))
```

Everything else remains the same.

Latter type is a little trickier, and technically doesn't benefit from it being a stream-related solution at all.

What you need is this:

```
public List<SummaryResult> toSummaryResultList(Map<String, Integer> resultMap) {
  List<SummaryResult> list = new ArrayList<>(resultMap.size());
  for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : resultMap.entrySet()) {
    String name = entry.getKey();
    Integer value = entry.getValue();

    // replace below with construction method you actually have
    list.add(SummaryResult.withName(name).andResult(value));
  }
  return list;
}
```

You can use this as part of collector composition, where your whole collector will get wrapped into a `collectingAndThen` call:

```
collectingAndThen(
  groupingBy(sample -> convertType(sample.getTypeId()),
     collectingAndThen(
       groupingBy(Sample::getSampleType,
         summingInt(Sample::getSampleQuantity)),
         map -> map.getOrDefault(SampleType.ADD, 0)
                - map.getOrDefault(SampleType.SUBTRACT, 0))),
  result -> toSummaryResultList(result))
```

However, as you can see, it is the whole collector that gets wrapped, so there is no real benefit in my eyes to the above version to a simpler and easier to follow (at least to me) version below that uses an intermediate variable, but isn't so much of a wall of code:

```
// do the whole collecting thing like before
Map<String, Integer> map = sampleList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(sample -> convertType(sample.getTypeId()),
            Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                Collectors.groupingBy(Sample::getSampleType,
                    Collectors.summingInt(Sample::getSampleQuantity)),
                        map -> map.getOrDefault(SampleType.ADD, 0)
                                - map.getOrDefault(SampleType.SUBTRACT, 0))));

// return the "beautified" result
return toSummaryResultList(map);
```

Another point to consider in above is: `convertType` method will be called as many times as there are elements in `sampleList`, so if `convertType` call is "heavy" (for example, uses database or IO), then it's better to call it as part of `toSummaryResultList` conversion, not as stream element classifier. In which case you will be collecting from map of type `Map<Integer, Integer>` still, and using `convertType` inside the loop. I will not add any code with this in consideration, as I view this change as trivial.

Comment: as of now, the convertType is a simple if-else to grab the String, or maybe ENUM value. So I don't think it's heavy, but I do see that having the convert done inside the Map.Entry loop might be better too. Also, with regards to the convertType(id) as mentioned in your first few lines > String convertType(int typeId) <. It should be a String convertType (Sample sample). So the parameter seem to be required as a object instead of int. As I can't do a group like this groupingBy(sample -> convertType(sample.getTypeId)).

Comment: @user1778855, it doesn't actually need to accept `Sample` as input, it's the outer part that needs changing. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I'm still getting some issue with the convertType. See my updated post with the convertType method with your suggestion to change the first classifier. It is complaining to me (Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<Object,Object> to Map<String,Integer>).

Comment: @user1778855, that doesn't happen for me. The latter code block compiles just fine for me. If it doesn't try adding type qualifiers to various parts (lambdas, collectors, etc.).

Comment: my bad, I passed in the wrong parameter. Should have been a long instead of a int for convertType method param.

Answer (score 0):

You could indeed use a map() function

```
sampleList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Sample::getSampleTypeId,
                Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                        Collectors.groupingBy(Sample::getSampleType,
                                Collectors.summingInt(Sample::getSampleQuantity)),
                        map -> map.getOrDefault(SampleType.ADD, 0)
                                - map.getOrDefault(SampleType.SUBTRACT, 0))))
        .entrySet()            
        .stream()            
        .map(entry->new SummaryResult(entry.getKey()),entry.getValue())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Several questions: what is `entry` used on second line? If `getStringKeyFromLong` really returns `String`, then it's impossible to collect it as `Stream<Sample>` like you're doing. Finally, what is the second `map()` called on? The `Map` doesn't have that method.

Comment: thanks, forgot to stream() the result again, and removed the stub getStringKeyFromLong. I just considered to map the entries to string beforehand and then read again and  paid attention that the OP would prefer to receive a new object anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
ToIntFunction<Sample> signedQuantityMapper= sample -> sample.getQuantity() 
    * (sample.getType() == Type.ADD ? 1 : -1);

Function<Sample, String> keyMapper = s -> Integer.toString(s.getTypeId());

Map<String, Integer> result = sampleList.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(
        keyMapper,
        Collectors.summingInt(signedQuantityMapper)));
```